# Timer how long it takes to load another activity

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, timer

I wanted to as you. Do you know how I can time how long it take to load another activity

example:

**Activity A**

```
    onCreate....
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        finish();
        //START THE TIMER HERE **************
        startActivity(myIntent);
...
```

**Activity B**

```
onCrate.....

loadPlayer();
....


private void loadPlayer() {

//Player has been loaded
//STOP THE TIME AND PRINT TO LOG CAT ***************
log.i("Timer", "It taken = ");

}
```

Comment: Either create a static reference to timer or instead of starting the timer before you start another activity you instead timed it before you call the `loadPlayer` method in the oncreate method of the activity

Comment: have a member variable, for example private long mTimer;
On start timer: mTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
On stop timer: log.i("Timer", System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimer);
Thats milliseconds btw.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small helper class that works perfect for my needs in a couple of simple apps:

```
public class Profiler {

    private static HashMap<String, Long> profileTimes;

    public static void startProfiling(String key) {
        profileTimes.put(key, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static void endProfiling(String key) {
        endProfiling(key, "");
    }

    public static void endProfiling(String key, String desc) {
        if (profileTimes.get(key) != null) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - profileTimes.get(key);
            Log.d("profiling", key + ", " + desc + ": time: " + (time / 1000) + "." + String.format("%03d", (time % 1000)));
            profileTimes.remove(key);
        } else {
            Log.e("profiling", "NO profiling found for key: " + key);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it just do `Profiler.startProfiling("ActivityB")` and when you consider it's loaded -> `Profiler.endProfiling("ActivityB")`

Answer (score 1):

You have to take two Global variables.

Suppose...

```
public static long TIME1, TIME2;
```

**Activity A**

```
onCreate....
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        finish();
        //START THE TIMER HERE **************

        TIME1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        startActivity(myIntent);
...
```

**Activity B**

```
private void loadPlayer() {

    //Player has been loaded
    //STOP THE TIME AND PRINT TO LOG CAT ***************

    TIME2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    log.i("Timer", "It taken = " + (TIME2 - TIME1));


    }
```